how do i get the name of a topic a message is sent in with Telethon
Basically, I need a self-bot to do the following:
On new messages, if the message is in a group that uses topics, get the topic name.
The docs aren’t helpful at all. Does Telethon even support topics? This is my first Telegram bot, so I’m not really sure what I’m doing.

I'm unsure about Elixir Techne's answer. I've been working with topics with Telethon and have never heard of forum_topic_id attribute nor using get_entity() to get topics. Would've been great if you could.
Finding the Topic ID
The way I've been doing it is to use the message's reply_to to determine the topic it was sent in. You can read my full answer here, but basically messages sent in a topic will have either reply_to_msg_id or reply_to_top_id (if it's a reply to another message in said topic) and forum_topic will be set to True.
Get the reply_to_top_id if it exists or use the reply_to_msg_id if it doesn't. It should be the topic ID (the message that broadcasts the creation of that topic).
Finding the Topic Name
Once you have the topic_id of the message, you can then find the topic name by using this function. This will return a ForumTopics object. What you want to do is extract the topics attribute and then get the title attribute.
topic_name = client(functions.channels.GetForumTopicsByIDRequest(channel=channel_id, topics=[topic_id])).topics[0].title

